# custom ribbon button on publishing page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon-control

I am trying to add button to page.Tried location to be Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.

But button doesn't display.Need some help on this.

Thanks
Rama

Answer (score 0):

It depends if it is a wiki page or webpart page, and which tab and group. Below are example that add ribbon to Wiki Page/ Share Tab and Web Part Page/Share Tab

Below are the element code:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.NewControlInExistingGroup"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" Sequence="20">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.Share.Controls._children">
          <Button .......... />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.WebPartPage.Share.Controls._children">
          <Button .......... />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
```

For other locations, you can refer to CMDUI.XML in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML

Have a look at the article that i refer to everytime i work on custom ribbons too.

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/02/customize-ribbon-programmatically-from.html